# Find the smallest number not representable by a set of numbers

Tags: algorithm

I am given {1,2,3,...,N} numbers. Now x<=N numbers are deleted.Find the smallest number that can't be represented as sum of these numbers.
Example:

> A={1,2,3,4} now if 1 number that is 3 is deleted then 8 can't be represented. So answer is 8. Is there any way we can find this in O(logN) time?
>   My algo:

```
 ans=1;
 let a[]={sorted list of numbers that are deleted}// here in example only 3
 for(i=1;i<=n and p<=ans ;i++)
     if(a[p]!=i)
        ans+=i;
     else
        p++;
 return ans;
```

Comment: Ah, homework time! What algorithm did you come up with? Or just give us the email of the guy who asked you the question, we can send the solution right there, saving you time!

Comment: the algorithm that i come up with-

Comment: @Morre:the algorithm that i come up with-is first sort the list of deleted numbers and then we use a loop that checks equality with a deleted number if they mismatch add the index otherwise we will increase the index variable associated with the sorted list. The index i is used to compare with other lists elements. If you please give me your email id I will give you the source code that is working in O(n) time.(through chat or message).

Comment: @Mörre: Can I show u my implementation. It's large to show here,I can mail u(chat with u).

Comment: You should not talk to _me_, but to all. There are plenty of ways to share code. And there should be no need to elicit additional vital information, just add it to your questions form the start. I mean, leaving out what you've got so far on your own, when would that ever _not_ be a good idea when asking a Q on SO?

Comment: @Mörre: Now I have added it. Can u please give me the O(logn) or O(1) idea.

Comment: Indeed? Just before you said _"It's large to show here"_, and now it's just 8 lines that you have to post? No I don't think I'll help. Just count your losses and try again better prepared next time.

Comment: @Mörre:actually I have not shown the routine for quicksort and then printing getting the I/O for in C++.

Comment: Which are irrelevant, as you (should) know, since you only want the actual algorithm. The criticism stands.

Comment: @Mörre: Thanks for not helping me.U really are good at this. Anyway thanks for your comments(atleast someone did that). Sorry if I have done/said anything wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should occasionally get a mirror - and look for the "guilty" party by looking at it's surface, at a 90 degree angle. Consider that one of your problems isn't the rest of the world, but yourself. Without self-reflection your outlook is bleak - or you become rich and a CEO.